# Was this sentence formed grammatically correct?

Tags: sentence-structure, writing, objects

"*The charts below show the results of a questionnaire that asked visitors to the Parkway Hotel how they rated the hotel's customer service*."

Does this information sentence above look grammatically correct? Doesn't it have to have any conjunction between
these two part?

[*The charts below show the results of a questionnaire that asked visitors to the Parkway Hotel*]  [*how they rated the hotel's customer service*]

Comment: It's clumsy but it appears to be grammatically correct. It certainly needs rewording to make it easier to understand, but that it not what we are here to do. If you try to re-word it yourself, we may be able to help you.

Comment: +1 for writing *the charts below* and not *the below charts*.

Comment: There is a bit of an art to putting complex ideas into succinct sentences in English.  See if you start to get the idea from this: *The charts below show the results of a questionnaire asking Parkway [Hotel] visitors to rate the hotel's customer service.*  It helps to try to cut down on how many prepositional phrases you use.

Comment: @J.Doe so indeed,  this arrangment is much more comprehensible.

Answer (score 5):

No, you don't need a conjunction or anything else between the two clauses. To so would unnecessarily separate the two objects of *to ask*. Let's look at two  simpler sentences:

> John asked his friends something.
>
> John asked his friends how they rated  the movie.

The verb *to ask* can take two objects, traditionally called indirect (his friends) and direct (something/how they rated the movie). There's no need to separate them, since the verb governs the syntax of what follows it.

Adding to the length and complexity of the sentence does not change things, as far as that is concerned.

And again, +1 for writing *the charts below* and not *the below charts*.

To address your question in the comment, *visitors to the Parkway Hotel* is one noun phrase, with *to the Parkway hotel* describing which visitors. It would be like saying

> John asked [his friends from Bulgaria]  how they rated  the movie.

Comment: but aren't there 3 objects in this sentence ? "Asked (visitors) to the (Parkway Hotel)  (how they rated the hotel's customer service)

Comment: @CavidHummatov - "visitors to the Parkway Hotel" is one object, not two.  *to the Parkway Hotel* only modifies *visitors*; it doesn't play a separate role in the sentence.